# display paragraph content within a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a width changes dynamically. And inside the div, I want to display a paragraph but my paragraph keep getting out of the div. How can I fix that problem?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="session session_1">
    </div>
    <div class="session session_2">
        <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
div.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    background: black;
}
div.session {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div.session_1 {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
div.session_2 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJGZU/256/)

Comment: just use overflow-x:auto property in css div.session2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this

```css
div.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  background: black;
}
div.session {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div.session_1 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
div.session_2 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="session session_1">
  </div>
  <div class="session session_2">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your CSS, the `<div>` that contains your paragraph (that is `.session_2`), add `word-wrap: break-word;`

Example (based on fiddle):

```
div.session_2 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change css as

```
div.session_2 {

height: 100px;
background: red;
overflow-x:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TJGZU/259/